# How to execute Vertx Future in sequential order

Tags: vert.x

In my sample project, I tried to do some initialization work when the application is started.

- Java 16
- Vertx 4.1.0

Check [the complete project codes](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/blob/master/graphql/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DataInitializer.java).

```java
log.info("Data initialization is starting...");
        var deleteComments = this.comments.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted comments: {}", event));
        var deletePosts = this.posts.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted posts: {}", event));
        var deleteUsers = this.authors.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted users: {}", event));

        //log.info("deleted rows: authors: {}, comments: {}, posts: {}", authorsDel, commentsDel, postDel);
        var insertData = this.authors.create("user", "user@example.com").onSuccess(
            authorId -> {
                IntStream.range(1, 5)
                    .forEach(
                        i -> {
                            this.posts.create("Dgs post #" + i, "test content of #" + i, PostStatus.DRAFT.name(), authorId).onSuccess(
                                postId -> {

                                    IntStream.range(1, new Random().nextInt(5) + 1)
                                        .forEach(c -> this.comments.create("comment #" + c, postId));
                                }
                            );

                        }
                    );
            }
        );

        var printPosts = this.posts.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("post: {}", p));
        var printComments = this.comments.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("comment: {}", p));
        var printAuthors = this.authors.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("author: {}", p));

        deleteComments
            .flatMap(integer -> deletePosts)
            .flatMap(integer -> deleteUsers)
            .flatMap(integer -> insertData)
            .flatMap( uuid -> printPosts)
            .flatMap(postEntities -> printComments)
            .flatMap(commentEntities -> printAuthors)
            .onSuccess(event -> log.info("done"));
        log.info("done data initialization...");
```

But it does not work as expected.

1. There is no a `then` method like Reactor.
2. And the `Future.result()` will return an exception instead of a blocking call(how to make execution in a blocking way, I thought it is a blocking invocation).

I can not find an effective way to execute them in sequential order.

**Update**:

I changed the codes as suggested.

```java
  this.comments.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted comments: {}", event))
            .flatMap(r -> this.posts.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted posts: {}", event)))
            .flatMap(r -> this.authors.deleteAll().onSuccess(event -> log.info("deleted users: {}", event)))
            .flatMap(r -> this.authors.create("user", "user@example.com")
                .onSuccess(
                    authorId -> {
                        log.info("inserted user: {}", authorId);
                        IntStream.range(1, 5)
                            .forEach(
                                i -> {
                                    this.posts.create("Dgs post #" + i, "test content of #" + i, PostStatus.DRAFT.name(), authorId).onSuccess(
                                        postId -> {
                                            log.info("inserted post: {}", postId);
                                            IntStream.range(1, new Random().nextInt(5) + 1)
                                                .forEach(c -> this.comments.create("comment #" + c, postId)
                                                    .onSuccess(id -> log.info("inserted comment: {}", id))
                                                );
                                        }
                                    );

                                }
                            );
                    }
                )
            )
            .flatMap(r -> this.posts.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("saved posts: {}", p)))
            .flatMap(r -> this.comments.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("saved comments: {}", p)))
            .flatMap(r -> this.authors.findAll().onSuccess(p -> log.info("saved authors: {}", p)))
            .onSuccess(event -> log.info("done data initialization..."));
```

And got the following log in the console.

```sh
10:20:46.699 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - Data initialization is starting...
10:20:47.768 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.MainVerticle - HTTP server started on port 8080
10:20:47.768 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  i.v.c.i.l.c.VertxIsolatedDeployer - Succeeded in deploying verticle
10:20:47.918 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - deleted comments: 10
10:20:47.942 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - deleted posts: 4
10:20:47.960 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - deleted users: 1
10:20:48.022 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted user: 260fee93-cf60-408d-a3e9-f7b08ed7545a
10:20:48.047 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - saved posts: []
10:20:48.052 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted post: 57a936e2-9611-43b5-94e2-1b01069cd327
10:20:48.056 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - saved comments: []
10:20:48.067 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - saved authors: [AuthorEntity[id=260fee93-cf60-408d-a3e9-f7b08ed7545a, name=user, email=user@example.co
m, createdAt=null]]
10:20:48.092 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - done data initialization...
10:20:48.112 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted post: 534b99ae-4847-4cea-84c1-88cea87f20b7
10:20:48.117 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted post: f7dca2eb-0954-4368-b9b6-68a00f6748f2
10:20:48.120 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted post: 02e8f84f-25dd-4d69-b7f1-8c125ce35bc1
10:20:48.131 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted comment: b9bf618a-f579-48f5-96cc-51f962ca041c
10:20:48.134 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted comment: 052cfde8-627d-4cb3-8812-5543673a20ea
10:20:48.143 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted comment: 69a5dc2b-30f8-4008-90a1-e8c724336dcd
10:20:48.149 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  com.example.demo.DataInitializer - inserted comment: a19c2626-1546-4ba0-a663-823df08d836f
```

How to make sure all futures in the **insert** block are completed before entering the **print** result.

Comment: Can you share the logs of this snippet?

Comment: @Selim The printed log is in a different order every time when running the appliction.

Comment: You can use a [Composite Future](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/CompositeFuture.html) for the insert block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because your `deleteAll` and `findAll` operations are not lazy. Because of this, they are running as soon as you call them. Instead of doing:

```java
deleteComments
  .flatMap(integer -> deletePosts)
  ...
```

You want to be doing this:

```java
deleteComments
  .flatMap(integer -> this.posts.deleteAll())
  ...
```

This will make sure that they will run sequentially. If you want something that's more similar to Reactor, you can take a look at the [RxJava3 extensions](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java3/) or [mutiny bindings](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/2.7.0/) for Vert.x.

Comment: Thanks , this is helpful for me. I also tried the rxjava2/rxjava 3 integration and kotlin coroutines(not simple as Spring) feature sin vertex.

Comment: @Hantsy can you mark this answer as accepted in that case? :-)